# I want to get back my whole dynamic web project from openshift ,how could i get back it in my local server (eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, openshift, recover

I have made a project and I made it online through Openshift.My project is still online on openshift URL http://easynote-sansari.rhcloud.com/ , but due to mistake is deleted from my local server.
I want to get back my project in my local server for further improvement. Please help me to get my project back from Openshift.

thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you uploaded your project to OpenShift Online, you have a couple of options for recovering your files.

1. [SCP](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/common-rhc-commands.html#backup-commands)/SFTP : You can use a file transfer program that supports the SCP or SFTP protocols to download the files for your website, which should be located in your ~/app-root/repo directory.
2. [Git](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/modifying-applications.html#using-git-repository) : If you were using Git to add/push your files to your OpenShift online application, you can re-clone your application to your local machine using the `rhc git-clone` command.
3. [Download an Archived Backup](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/backing-up-applications.html) : You can use the `rhc snapshot-save` command to created an archived backup of your application, which will then be downloaded to your local machine.  You can then decompress the archive and extract your files.

Comment: I am using git add/push. I had cloned my application using git-clone command ,but the application only backups the jsp file and there is no java file at all.
It only contains .openshift, .setting, webapp and in web app there a WAR file , after extracting this WAR file it only contains the jsp file.
Where is src folder?

Comment: it sounds more like you were adding the WAR file to the git repo and doing a git push, in which case OpenShift did not contain a copy of your source files.